# How can I use translate laravel config file

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.3, and I've a config file, which is calling `trans()` function. When I run `php artisan`, It will give me an error

```
Class translator does not exist
```

This is my config file

```
<?php

return [
'modules' => [
        'name'      =>  trans('menus.module'),
        'url'       =>  'modules',
    ],
];
```

Comment: have you tried `composer update` to reload class mapping

Comment: @Cybersupernova No that would not work. Simply because at this point `TranslatorServiceProvider` or any service provider isn't loaded yet.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: YOU CAN'T.

The long answer:
Config files are loaded before the application is bootstrapped, so there is no Translator class because it hasn't been loaded yet.

You should also not be doing that if you plan to cache the config, as you see, it will not work as expected.

You can change it at run-time by doing something like this.

```
$config = Config::get('Your Key');
$trans = trans($config);
```